# add_filter() wordpress not fired inside plugin class

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to rename an image during the upload process of wordpress. I wrote a simple plugin but it seems that the filter I want to use is not fired. Can anyone help me?

```
  public function rename_image( $file )
  {
    $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $file['name'] = md5($file['name']) . $info['extension'];
    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'process_upload' );
    return $file;
  }

  public function process_upload()
  {
    $upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['imageFile'], array( 'test_form' => false ));

    if( $upload ){
      $p = $this->process_image( $upload['file'], $_POST['message'] );
      var_dump($p);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is the plugin running but you're not getting the desired output? It's hard to tell what exactly is happening with the information given.

Comment: @MattK yes, I'm testing the plugin on my localhost wp installation. It will not rename the image during the upload process, the `process_image` method is to do some steganography operations, but works fine. I've tried to add the filter in the class construct on the rename_image method but still not work